# How to set object value using List<Object> to a model class in java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

how do add each property value in my model using List? Here is what i do

here is my object :
**Item.java**

```
public class Item {

    private String code;

    private String name;

    private Integer qty;

    // skip the getter setter
}
```

here is how i want to add the value from another class

```
List<Item> sBarang = new ArrayList<Item>();
sBarang.add("");
```

How do I add each property value my Item.java?

What I can do is something like this :

```
Item mItem = new Item();
mItem .setCode("101");
mItem .setName("Hammer");
mItem .setQty(10);
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking... `sBarang.add(mItem)` is how you add an item to a list of items. You can't add an individual item value to a list of items, because it's a list of items, not strings/integers/etc. If you have a list of objects you'd need to set them individually and hope they're in the right order. What are you specifically trying to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something you just need to add your `mItem` to your `List`. Like

```
Item mItem = new Item(); // <-- instantiate a new Item.
mItem.setCode("101");
mItem.setName("Hammer");
mItem.setQty(10);
sBarang.add(mItem); // <-- add it to your List<Item>.
```

You could also create a new `Item` constructor that looks something like

```
public Item(String code, String name, Integer qty) {
    this.code = code;
    this.name = name;
    this.qty = qty;
}
```

and then use a single line add like

```
sBarang.add(new Item("101", "Hammer", 10));
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a constructor for your convenience.

```
public class Item {
    public Item(String code, String name, int qty){
        this.code=code;
        this.name=name;
        this.qty=qty;
    }
    private String code;

    private String name;

    private Integer qty;

    //skip the getter setter
}
```

Since then, you can add new "Item" object easily by

```
sBarang.add(new Item("101","Hammer",10));
```

Answer (score 1):

`sBarang.add("")` is not going to work. Your trying to add a `String` to a list containing only `Item` objects.

The second half of your post sounds like you're looking for a more efficient way to assign values to the fields of your `Item` instance. Do this by adding a constructor to your class. That will look like this:

```
public class Item {

    public Item (String startCode, String startName, int startQty) {
        this.code = startCode;
        this.name = startName;
        this.qty = startQty;
    }
    ...
}
```

Initialize your item like this: `Item myItem = new Item("101", "Hammer", 10);`

Add it to your list like this: `sBarang.add(myItem);`

Or use the one-liner: `sBarang.add(new Item("101", "Hammer", 10));`

Answer (score 0):

```
 Item m= new Item(); 
    m.Set_Code("101");
    m.set_Name("Hammer");
    m.set_Qty(10);
    s_barang . add(m); 
    i need to store the next value but always i get the last value in the array how to clear the current data from model class object and push the next item into m...
```